# Why does setting @controller in specs cause ActionView::MissingTemplate errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My rspec tests have started throwing errors

`ActionView::MissingTemplate:`

e.g. `Missing template users/index` is being raised by `./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb`

These templates definitely exist.

After much debugging, I have traced this back to another controller spec that is testing a reputation/points system. Because reputation is applied across various controllers and actions, I am setting up each spec something like the following:

```
#./spec/controllers/reputation_rules_spec.rb
describe 'Reputation Rules', type: :controller do
  describe "update user" do
    before :each do
      @controller = UsersController.new
    end
    it 'tests that reputation is adjusted' 
  end
  describe "tests reptation on other controller/action combinations"....
end
```

If I comment out the `@controller` line, the `missing template` errors disappear, but of course the reputation spec then fails.

Why is this `@controller` line influencing tests outside the current spec?

Do I need to somehow reset `@controller` after the test, or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding

```
#./spec/controllers/reputation_rules_spec.rb
after :all do 
  @controller = nil
end
```

but am still unclear why `@controller` is persisting into other tests